# Node js : search dynamic json object in Json array

Tags: node.js

I have following JSON data,

```
var configs =   [{
                    "port" : "3003", 
                    "mongoURI" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest", 
                    "MQ" : "RMQ", 
                    "logLevel" : "2", 
                    "version" : "1.1", 
                    "created" : "03-06-2018 03:11:00 PM", 
                    "active" : "N"
                }, 
                {
                    "port" : "3004", 
                    "mongoURI" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest", 
                    "MQ" : "IMQ", 
                    "logLevel" : "1", 
                    "version" : "1.2", 
                    "created" : "07-06-2018 03:11:00 PM", 
                    "active" : "Y"
                }, 
                {
                    "port" : "3003", 
                    "mongoURI" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest", 
                    "MQ" : "Apache Cafka", 
                    "logLevel" : "3", 
                    "version" : "1.3", 
                    "created" : "03-06-2018 03:11:00 PM", 
                    "active" : "Y"
                }, 
                {
                    "port" : "3003", 
                    "mongoURI" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest", 
                    "MQ" : "RMQ", 
                    "logLevel" : "3", 
                    "version" : "1.4", 
                    "created" : "03-06-2018 03:11:00 PM", 
                    "active" : "Y"
                }]
```

And, I have following dynamic json object.

```
var cloudParam = {
        "MQ" : "RMQ",
        "logLevel" : "2"
    }
```

Dynamic means, key-Value pair in `cloudParam` is not fixed. Rightnow it have `MQ &  LogLevel`, but next time it will be, `MQ,loglevel & version` - Basically it is not fixed.

So, i want to find json object which contains `cloudParam`.
I tried below code, but i am not getting json obj.

```
for(i = 0; i < configs.length ; i++){
    var configItem = configs[i];
    for (var item in cloudParam) {        
        if(item in configItem && configItem[item] === cloudParam[item]){
            console.log("Present");
        } else {
            console.log("Not Present");
        }
    }    
}
```

`EDIT`:@Aks, thanks for answer, If i want to find index of matched document, how to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` and `every`.
You can use `.find` instead of `.filter` if you only need one match.

```
var cloudParam = {
  MQ: "RMQ",
  logLevel: "2"
};

console.log(
  configs.filter(config =>
    Object.keys(cloudParam).every(key => config[key] === cloudParam[key])
  )
);
```

Comment: If i want to find out index of matching object, then how to find it.

Comment: if there  [ logLevel: "2" ] is present two times in the original array i.e. in config array, it will return 2 objects, I want exact match.

Comment: Like I said in the answer: "You can use .find instead of .filter if you only need one match."